# Using a keyword as an alias in Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, alias, keyword, reserved-words

I want to use the keyword order as an alias of an expression in the SELECT clause.

To reproduce, insert the following into a Cosmos DB collection.

```
{
    "name": "John Doe"
}
```

The following query works fine

```
SELECT 
    c.name 
  , c["order"]    
  , c["order"] ?? "defaultValue" 
  , c["order"] ?? "defaultValue" as order2
FROM c
WHERE c.name = 'John Doe'
```

This one fails because I am using the keyword order

```
SELECT 
    c.name 
  , c["order"]    
  , c["order"] ?? "defaultValue" 
  , c["order"] ?? "defaultValue" as order2
  , c["order"] ?? "defaultValue" as order
FROM c
WHERE c.name = 'John Doe'
```

I have tried using square brackets, double quotes, and single quotes to surround the alias like SQL Server allows.

Comment: You're attempting to create an alias that's already a reserved word. I doubt that would be possible to do. Even if it was possible, it seems like an anti-pattern remapping a reserved word to mean something different.

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge,cosmos db only supports querying a field name that uses a reserved word.

```
SELECT c["top"] FROM c
```

I'm afraid that you can't use reserved word on alias because it can't be correctly identified as smooth SQL statement. In addition, I also think this approach will cause ambiguity which is extremely not recommended in SQL.

Comment: Why cannot I use square brackets?  Are you saying that I can never use a key word as an attribute name?  If so, it would be good to have a warning show up somewhere. What do you do when this is the attribute name for already existing data?

Answer (score 0):

A little bit ugly, but this syntax works for Cosmos:

```
SELECT VALUE {'order':c["order"]} FROM c WHERE c.name='John Doe'
```

And would be the rough equivalent of regular SQL:

```
SELECT c.[order] as [order] FROM c WHERE c.name='John Doe'
```